# Form submit after calculation script complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Variations of this questions have been asked before, but I haven't been able to fix it for the way I set my website up.

Basically, I have a website where the user can create a project. The user can add as many tasks to this project as he wants to, and each task has a number that adds to a total sum at the end. Usually, the Javascript function (`TotalSum()`) that I developed for this calculation works perfectly, but some users want to be able to use the Enter key to submit the form. While it does indeed submit the form as you'd expect, it doesn't launch the calculation function and instead skips straight to the submission of the form. This leads to numbers being submitted that may no longer be accurate to calculations.

TotalSum() is launched after a number input field is altered and the user either clicks out, clicks on the 'Submit' button or whatever else you'd expect – all except for the automatic submission via the Enter key.

My intent is to only allow submission of the form **after** the function has finished calculating and filled all the input fields with the new numbers. How could I best go about doing that?

I've tried various ways to go about this, but usually preventing the form from submitting also seems to stop me from submitting it again.

```
$('#form_project').submit(function (e) {
    TotalSum();
    // TotalSum(); is done calculating, proceed with submitting the form away!
});
```

I could also use PHP to just do the calculation after the form is submitted, but coding in PHP what Javascript is already doing fine by itself, if it was properly allowed to finish calculating by the Enter key, just seems like a messy solution.

jQuery is absolutely an option. How could I best go about doing this?

Comment: Use **[$.deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/)**

Comment: How can I best use .deferred (I think .always or .done would best serve my purposes) to work with my function TotalSum()? So that jquery lets TotalSum finish before proceeding to submit the entire form.

Comment: Exactly.. It will wait for `promise` to be completed

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for this purpose and check if the enter key is pressed using

```
$(document).keypress(function(key) {
   if(key.which == 13) {     // 13 is ascii for enter key
       //Use your totalSum function
         TotalSum();
   }
});
```

Comment: One of my attempts included me doing just that, but I believe my function needs a few seconds to finish calculating – it uses a few animations which smoothly change the numbers to better illustrate to the user that calculations are happening. Is it possible to let my function run, even if it takes a few seconds to complete, before letting the form submission go wild?